# kml gx track dynamic update from real time data

Tags: kml, google-earth

I want to get coordinates every second and update the track on google earth in the kml file

I know i need a network link with an update that is added coordinates with the time and refresh it every second but i couldn't find any complete examples that show this and the update part is confusing me. I was wondering if someone could write out a simple example?

Answer (score 0):

If you want to generate KML and update on a regular interval then you create a root KML such as this:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<kml xmlns="http://www.opengis.net/kml/2.2">
  <NetworkLink>
    <name>NetworkLink example</name>
    <Link>
          <href>http://...</href>
          <refreshMode>onInterval</refreshMode>
          <refreshInterval>5</refreshInterval>
    </Link>
  </NetworkLink>
</kml>
```

If your area of interest is a "small" or locallized then you may want to add a [Region](https://developers.google.com/kml/documentation/kmlreference#region) to the NetworkLink and [viewRefreshMode](https://developers.google.com/kml/documentation/kmlreference#viewrefreshmode) element with *onRegion* value to only refresh when the region is active (e.g., within the current view).

```
  <NetworkLink>
    <name>NetworkLink example with Region</name>
    <Region>
    </Region>
    ...
    <Link>
          <href>http://...</href>
          <refreshMode>onInterval</refreshMode>
          <refreshInterval>5</refreshInterval>
          <viewRefreshMode>onRegion</viewRefreshMode>
    </Link>
  </NetworkLink>
```

For [NetworkLinkControl](https://developers.google.com/kml/documentation/kmlreference#networklinkcontrol) a tutorial can be found here with a working example.
https://developers.google.com/kml/documentation/updates

Comment: Thanks for the help
But i am actually trying to use gx:tracks and the networklink control with the update of a kml file was confusing me because i have to dynamically create the kml file on every interval and thats the part i am confused on

Comment: Don't blame you, the documentation for NetworkLinkControl is poor. I've added link to an existing tutorial and working example.

Comment: Iv looked at that but i need to do something a little different.
One is that i want to use track (is this the best thing to use for real time animation?)
And second is that i need to call a python script to generate new data and then add it to the track every second and the example shows static files

Comment: I see that this is old, but I am in search of the same type of thing and yes I do believe that there is no better form of animation with KML that is nearly as simple as the gx:Track